# Netbeans IDE scaling too small

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8.2

The Netbeans IDE menu icons(new project, open project, etc) are all extremely small. Any pop-up menus that open while I am working start with very small dimensions, forcing me to expand them so I can see what I am doing.

How do I increase these sizes?

I looked up a solution that involved editing the `netbeans.conf` file, but if I tried to save the edits, the computer said I needed admin permission(I am an admin in the computer).

[image]

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit netbeans.conf you text editor must be running in administrative mode. In order to put it in administrator mode follow these steps.

`1.) Use the windows search bar and search for the text editor you want to use.
 2.) right click on it and then click on "Run as administrator"
 3.) use your text editor to open the netbeans.conf`

Now you should be able to edit it.